# Regular expression for anchor tags

Tags: html, regex

When I try to write a regular expression to match anchor tags that takes the link in href as group 2 and text of anchor tag as group 3 as following:

`<a( href=\"(\S+)\")?.*>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)<\/a>`

to match this text:

`hello there <a href="Hello/world1">Hello World1</a><b>How are You<b><a href="Hello/world2">Hello World2</a>`

But instead of match `Hello World1` for group 3 it matches `Hello World2`. Can someone please help me write a regular expression to match group2 = `Hello/world1` and group2 = `Hello World2`.
Thanks.

[image: Click to see...]

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, there are too many possible variations. Use a DOM parser library.

Comment: Yeah, but my task here is to solve this using regular expressions.

Comment: Use a non-greedy `.*?` instead of `.*`. Or use `[^>]*` so it won't go past the first `>`.

Comment: I don't see how group 3 can match either of those things, because `[a-zA-Z0-9]` doesn't match the space between the words.

Comment: Please look at the image that I've added to the question. That is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Your regexp there is different from what you wrote in the question, it has a space after `0-9`.

Comment: Go back to your textbook or tutorial and read the section on about greedy matching.

Comment: Try this,
**<a(.*href\=\"(\S+)\")?[\w\s\S]*>([\w\s]+)<\/a>**
https://regex101.com/r/2eIaHj/2

Answer (score 1):

the proper syntax for the example you have given would look something like:

```
(?:<a(?: href=[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>(?!<a)?))+
```

but using regex to parse html is highly unrecommended, as a language parser would be much more efficient and capeable of handling all possible situations that could occur in html.